# How To Pass An Array Of Data Into A JSON Request Swift

Tags: json, swift, google-maps, geocoding

I am trying to take information from a Firebase snapshot of each child within a certain branch of the database and pass it into a function which uses a google API request. However, instead of passing in one lot of information, completing the function, and then doing the same for the next lot of information it is instead passing all the information all at once. This is leading the url only getting one address instead of all of them. I am getting the error "Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444" too.

Code For Getting The Snapshot:

```
func fetchSalonsForMarkers() {

let ref = Database.database().reference()
    
    let _ = ref.child("user_profile").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject] {
            
            let snapshotChildData = child.value as! [String : AnyObject]
            var uniqueSalonData = Salon()
            
            for (key, value) in snapshotChildData {
                uniqueSalonData.acceptedTerms = snapshotChildData["acceptedterms"] as? String
                uniqueSalonData.acceptedTermsModdifiedAt = snapshotChildData["acceptedtermsmoddifiedat"] as? String
                uniqueSalonData.businessName = snapshotChildData["businessname"] as? String
                uniqueSalonData.companyAddressCounty = snapshotChildData["companyaddresscounty"] as? String
                uniqueSalonData.companyAddressPostCode = snapshotChildData["companyaddresspostcode"] as? String
                uniqueSalonData.companyAddressStreet = snapshotChildData["companyaddressstreet"] as? String
                uniqueSalonData.companyAddressTown = snapshotChildData["companyaddresstown"] as? String
                uniqueSalonData.companyEmail = snapshotChildData["companyemail"] as? String
                uniqueSalonData.companyMobilePhone = snapshotChildData["companymobilephone"] as? Int
                uniqueSalonData.ownerFirstName = snapshotChildData["ownerFirstName"] as? String
                uniqueSalonData.ownerLastName = snapshotChildData["ownerLastName"] as? String
                uniqueSalonData.stripeCustomerId = snapshotChildData["stripeCustomerId"] as? String
            }
            self.salons.append(uniqueSalonData)
            self.longLatLookUp(street: uniqueSalonData.companyAddressStreet ?? "Street Error", town: uniqueSalonData.companyAddressTown ?? "Town Error", county: uniqueSalonData.companyAddressCounty ?? "County Error", postcode: uniqueSalonData.companyAddressPostCode ?? "Postcode Error", businessName: uniqueSalonData.businessName ?? "Name Error")
        }
    })
}
```

Code For API Call(Google Geocoding)

```
 func longLatLookUp(street: String, town : String, county: String, postcode: String, businessName: String) {
        
        let completeSalonAddress = ("\(street) \(county) Scotland")
        let formattedSalonAddress = completeSalonAddress.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

        let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(formattedSalonAddress)&key=APIKEY")!
       //API Key does have valid key.

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data)
            let salonLat = json?.results[0].geometry.location.lat
            let salonLng = json?.results[0].geometry.location.lng
            self.addMarkers(lat: salonLat!, lng: salonLng!, businessName: businessName)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Code For Adding Markers(For Context):

```
func addMarkers(lat: Double, lng: Double, businessName: String) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat , longitude: lng)
        marker.title = businessName
        marker.snippet = "Test"
        marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
        let markerPic: UIImage = UIImage(named: "AppIcon")!
        marker.icon = markerPic
        marker.map = self.mapView
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated but the `for (key, value)...` loop is pointless.

Comment: Yeah I've removed it and still no difference :( Thanks for the tip though!